# ListView.setAdapter(new String[]{}) - и не более того, БЕЗ R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Tags: java, android, listview

Я на Android создаю свой `AlertDialog` с нужным мне содержимым:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(...)
        .setView(R.layout.layout_settings) // вот моя Layout
        .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface i1, int i3) {
                ...
                return;
            }
            
        })
        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface i1, int i3) {
                ...
                return;
            }
            
        })
        .create()
        .show();
```

В этой моей Layout `R.layout.layout_settings` есть `ListView`:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Как в него **элементарно** добавить `String[]` массив со значениями? Вот безо всяких этих `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` как написано [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/82-urok42-spisok-listview.html). Не работает! Вылетает исключение:

> java.lang.NullPointerException:
>
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Мне нужно **просто и элементарно** указать моему `ListView` обычный `String[]`
массив. С этими не буду выражаться "simple_list_item.." проще застрелиться.

Никакие дополнительные XML файлы (к примеру Layout) для какого-то маловажного списка `ListView` я создавать не собираюсь. Нужен другой вариант.

Comment: в какой строке Exception? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 не требует от тебя создания каких-либо XML, он берет стандартный элемент.

Comment: Exception в строке `myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{...});`. Извините, забыл её указать в вопросе.

Comment: а как получаешь объект myListView?

Comment: (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);

Comment: Ну скорее всего поэтому и NullPointer, потому что надо ListView искать на диалоге , т.е. dialog.findViewById

Comment: А я его до открытия диалога получаю. Иначе никак, он у меня глобально используется.

Comment: Вы получает listView, который лежит в диалоге, до того как добавили диалог? думаете он не будет null? в режиме отладки остановитесь на строчке setAdapter и посмотрите чему равен `myListView`

Comment: Хм, а как тогда я его в диалоге получу?

Comment: У `AlertDialog.Builder`'а есть метод `setItems`. По-моему элементарнее добавить String[] в диалог не бывает...

Comment: @YuraIvanov, Нет нет, там не один ListView в Layout'е, там ещё и TextView'ов 4 штуки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

    }
});

dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton( "cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

    }
});

ListView myListView = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.lv);
//добавляешь адаптер
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: а что такое myDialog на седьмой строке?..

Comment: @L'Esperanza, лишняя строка. Работает?

Comment: Оценка 5. **Супер!**. Спасибо.